# What is a general name for a group of people who support and defend a cause or ideal?

Tags: single-word-requests

Adherent ("a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower") is the word I am considering. For example, would a group of people who support and fight for freedom be called adherents (ignoring the obvious "freedom fighter")?

Comment: There are plenty of words depending on the level of fanaticism and insult you want to imply. Did you look here already:
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/supporter?s=t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the word follower or activist, militant or even advocate:

http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=advocate

http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=activist

Etc.

Comment: "Militant" is interesting. It suggests an unquestioning belief in a cause or ideal. Would you still use it if the group supported or adhered to, say, honesty/dishonesty or fidelity/infidelity?